# jQuery Form Validation and Syntax

Tags: jquery

I am trying to calculate this but it is not working. I also tried the debugger and it says i have a syntax error on this line `$("#button").click(function() {`

Here is my full jQuery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#form").validate({
            rules: {
                'wind': {
                    required: true,
                    positiveNumber:true  
                }
            },
            messages: {
                'wind': {
                    required: "This value is required",
                    positiveNumber:"Positive numbers only please"
                }
            }


$("#button").click(function() {
    var temp = Number($('input[name=temp]').val());
    var wind = Number($('input[name=wind]').val());
    var result = (temp - (1.5 * wind));
    $('#result').text(result + " Degree Celsius");

    });
});

});
```

html

```
            <form style="text-align:center;font-size:120%;" id="form">
    <label>
        <strong>Temperature</strong>
        <input name="temp" type="text" value="" id="temp">
    </label>
    <label>
        <strong>Wind Speed </strong>
        <input name="wind" type="text" value="" id="wind">
    </label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button value="Submit" id="button" class="button">Submit</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="reset" value="Reset" id="button1">Reset</button>
</form>

</div>
<div class="res">
    <div id="result"></div>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that `$("#button")` should be inside `$("#form").validate()`. Take it outside 
validate function
 but keep it inside  `$(document).ready(function()`

**EDIT**

Looking at your HTML now... In imports I dont see `jquery.validate.min.js` .. how will it work?

Refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257814/form-validation-using-jquery) for more insights

Comment: it just refreshes the page now

Comment: you have to add that? i had no idea and my instructor didn't say anything about it. let me try it and get back to you.

Comment: okay now its working but i get the answer and it disappears right away! :( and i am going through the refer question you just gave me

Answer (score 0):

Piece of cake, passed your code through [JSBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org) (its just a pretty-formatter tool), and showed me this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#form").validate({
         rules: {
             'wind': {
                 required: true,
                 positiveNumber: true
             }
         },
         messages: {
             'wind': {
                 required: "This value is required",
                 positiveNumber: "Positive numbers only please"
             }
         } 
         // NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE
         $("#button").click(function() {
             var temp = Number($('input[name=temp]').val());
             var wind = Number($('input[name=wind]').val());
             var result = (temp - (1.5 * wind));
             $('#result').text(result + " Degree Celsius");
         });
     }); // this guy should be where it screams notice
 });
```

The sample below shouldn't have syntax errors.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            'wind': {
                required: true,
                positiveNumber: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            'wind': {
                required: "This value is required",
                positiveNumber: "Positive numbers only please"
            }
        }
    });

    $("#button").click(function() {
        var temp = Number($('input[name=temp]').val());
        var wind = Number($('input[name=wind]').val());
        var result = (temp - (1.5 * wind));
        $('#result').text(result + " Degree Celsius");
    });
});
```

Comment: i will put my html here, wait